# API on subdomain and oauth

Tags: angularjs, api, symfony, oauth

I have an api on a subdomain : api.exemple.com written with symfony2 and my main application on exemple.com (SPA - AngularJs).

I would like to allow user to link their facebook account with their local account. I don't know how to proceed in order to authenticate through my app and use third party oauth provider.

Do you have any clue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the angular side, start by opening a new window and send your oauth handler a get request:

```
self.oauthConnect = function(provider)
{
  var url = apiPrefix + '/oauth/tokens/'. provider;
  oauthWindow = $window.open(url,'_blank', 'height=600, width=600, top=100, left=300, modal=yes');
  oauthWindow.focus();
};
```

Your PHP api site then redirects to the oauth provider site (i.e. facebook).  We use a new client window so our SPA keeps running in spite of the redirect.  The provider then presents their login screen and redirects with the oauth token information.

Your PHP api site does what it needs to and generates the actual authorization token (hint: use a json web token).  The site then returns an html page back to your angular app.

```
<body>
  <script>
    window.opener.oauthCallback('<?php echo $oauthToken; ?>');
  </script>
</body>
```

Your angular controller (that opened the window) will then be called with the oauth token.

```
$window.oauthCallback = function(oauthToken) 
{
  oauthWindow.close();
  oauthWindow = null;
  authManager.oauthToken = oauthToken;

  self.oauthSubmit();
};
```

Easy right?  Well not really but it works.  In my case I turn right around and:

```
POST /auth/tokens/oauthToken
```

to get the real application token.  That way my oauth service can be used for multiple applications.